# Should arguments be passed in the child class or the parent class

Tags: java

Let's say I have a class

```
public class Child {
    public Child(Object arg1) {
        super(arg1);
    }
}
```

and I have a parent class

```
public class Parent {
    Object object;
    public Parent(Object arg1) {
        this.object=arg1;
    }
}
```

So my question is which would be a better coding practice

1. Inserting the argument in the child and then passing it over to the parent

OR

2. Inserting the argument in the parent itself without going through the child.

For clarity's sake let's say currently the child does not need the argument.

Comment: I think second is better.

Comment: what's the relation between parent and child in above code?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry missed putting it in the code snippet. Child extends Parent. Parent and Child both are concrete classes

Comment: @dit Hypothetical questions are off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: @200_success and opinion based on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of your code, calling super will result to an error, you need to extend your Child to the parent ie.

```
    public class Child extends Parent{
...
   }
```

Since you created a constructor for the parent:

```
public Parent(Object arg1)
```

the no-arguement constructor is gone by default.
If the Parent needs this object how else will you then initialize the Parent when you create the Child?

```
  public Child() {
    super(); //ERROR
  }
```

`super()` now won't work cause you created constructor for the parent with a parameter. super is looking for `Parent()` without any arguements

Comment: Yes, Sorry missed putting Child extends Parent in the code snippet. Parent and Child are concrete classes

Comment: @BhagyashreeJog - yes concrete classes but parent does not have the no constructor arguement, still need this. if Child doesnt need and parent needs, when you initialize the child, you would have to call the setter of the parent just to set the object.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely number 2 if the Child doesn't need it.
That is based on having Child ***extends*** Parent.

However, if Child really doesn't need it, then you should probably have it as a private field, and set it through a public constructor, else why initialize this variable through the Child ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no meaning of talking this single post here. In your case, the `Object` of `Parent` is `default`. If it's `private` and you want to initialize the `Object` of `Parent`, you have to call `super(arg1)` in `Child(Object arg1)`. If the access permission of `Object` of `Parent` is `public` or `protected` which means `Parent` allows `Child` to access `Object`, then `super.object` or `super(arg1)` have no difference here. So, maybe you need to tell the difference of access permissions like `protected` `public` `private` and `default`, check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private/215505#215505).